# Как описать правильно аптечки в скрипте игрока?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создать новый тип бонуса на уровне - аптечки, которые могут хранить разную величину лечения. При соприкосновении аптечки с любым объектом, содержащим компонент Health, аптечка должна добавить объекту величину лечения и пропасть с игровой сцены.
Игрок содержит компонент Health.Мне нужно в скрипте игрока обратиться к методу

```
public void SetHealth(int bonusHealth)
{

health+= bonusHealth;

}
```

и прибавить тем самым бонусное здоровье к основному здоровью игрока.

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
 {
   if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("Tablet"))
   {
     Destroy(col.gameObject);
   }
 }
```

На данный момент у меня аптечки уничтожаются,но здоровье не прибавляют.Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы это хотели сделать?

```cs
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) 
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Tablet")) 
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
        SetHealth(/*здесь напишите сколько надо прибавить*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: Да,но у меня метод SetHealth() в скрипте Health,а обратиться к нему нужно из скрипта Player.

Comment: @Юрий а зачем у вас метод SetHealth() в скрипте Health а не Player?

Comment: Так как у меня написан отдельный компонент здоровье который прикреплён к игроку и он отвечает за здоровье и урон.Ну наверно будет правильнее метод SetHealth перенести в скрипт игрока.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
 {
   if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("Tablet"))
   {
     Destroy(col.gameObject);
     SetHealth(10);
   }
 }
}
```

Я получаю компонент Health и пишу метод внутри этого компонента.Так как компонент "Health"прикреплён к игроку,то аптечка собирается,а здоровье уходит игроку.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum HealPotionSize { Small, Medium, Large }

public class HealPotion : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private HealPotionSize _size;
    private int _healing;

    private void Start () {
        switch (_size) {
            case HealPotionSize.Small: _healing = 10; break;
            case HealPotionSize.Medium: _healing = 20; break;
            case HealPotionSize.Large: _healing = 30; break;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
        if (other.TryGetComponent<Player>(out Player player)) {
            player.SetHealth(_healing);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробную программу:)